# I am getting error while hitting payUmoney api https://secure.payu.in/_payment'

Tags: json-api, payumoney

Iam getting error invalid amount . my request parameters are as follows
  var data={
       key: 'mHnY4ZVe',
            salt: ' OseOWqkht7',
            service_provider: 'payu_paisa',
            hash: hash,
            amount:1,
            firstName:'ayushi',
            lastName:'gupta',
            phone:"989601451",
            email:"ayushigupta0294@gmail.com",
            productInfo:'car',
           surl: 'www.google.com',
        furl: 'www.facebook.com',
        txnid:txnid
};

Answer (score 0):

check whether they accept amount as '1' or '100' for one rupee or they may have a minimum amount limit, try with Rs 10 or above

Comment: I am getting the same error after change my amount from 1 to 100

Comment: var hashSequence=form_data.key + "|" + form_data.txnid + "|" + form_data.amount + "|" +form_data.productinfo + "|" + form_data.firstname + "|" + form_data.email  + '|||||||||||' + form_data.salt 
 var hash = sha512(hashSequence).toLowerCase();

Comment: in above i have mentioned my hash formula . what is wrong in that ?

Comment: var form_data = {
        key: 'O6KOh5ey',
        txnid: txnid,
        amount: 1500,
        productinfo: 'plan',
        firstname: 'ayushi',
        email:'ayushigupta0294@gmail.com',
        phone: '9898989898',
        Surl: 'http://localhost:3000/payment_success',
        Furl: 'http://localhost:3000/payment_failed',
        salt:"EzWfi8DfWY",
        service_provider: 'payu_paisa'
        //udf1: JSON.stringify({ userId: __user._id, type: type })
    }

Answer (score 0):

In PayU documentation the clearly mentioned below line :

Note: specify prices using the lowest currency unit e.g. in lowest currency unit for PLN, so 1000 is equal to 10 PLN. HUF is the exception – multiply this by 100.

[Read this](http://developers.payu.com/en/restapi.html#creating_new_order_api)

Below is sample request :

```
{
  "notifyUrl": "https://your.eshop.com/notify",
  "customerIp": "127.0.0.1",
  "merchantPosId": "145227",
  "description": "RTV market",
  "currencyCode": "PLN",
  "totalAmount": "21000",
  "products": [
    {
      "name": "Wireless mouse",
      "unitPrice": "15000",
      "quantity": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "HDMI cable",
      "unitPrice": "6000",
      "quantity": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

you have not passed any currency code etc. They have complete documentation. Just read once. Change your request accordingly

Comment: The above sample request is for this api https://secure.payu.com/api/v2_1/orders.

Comment: your request is wrong. It is totally different. http://developers.payu.com/en/restapi.html#order_data_retrieve. Read this and implement according to that.

Comment: I have to make a request for payment and through this api we can  retrieve the status and details of an order.

Comment: Contact their support with the request payload you are trying. they are always quick and helpful

Comment: my transaction is succesfull .. i am getting transaction successfull message on my mail id but not getting any response from payu server in return in surl .. please help me